# how to find out the FileType of an audio-file?

Tags: macos, core-audio, audiotoolbox, caf

i'm using Core-Audio/AudioToolbox (Extended Audio File services) to *read* audio files on OSX.

for my specific application, i need to find out, whether the file i opened successfully using `ExtAudioFileOpenURL()` is a CAF-file.

unfortunately i seem to miss how to do this properly, as i cannot retrieve the `AudioFileTypeID` from an `ExtAudioFileRef`.

(when writing such a file, i can define the type by passing the `AudioFileTypeID` to `ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL`; what about the reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like with my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083077), it turned out that i have to use the normal AudioAPI (rather than ExtAudio API)

```
static bool isCAF(const AudioFileID*file) {
  /* trying to read format (is it caf?) */
  UInt32 format=0;
  UInt32 formatSize=sizeof(format);
  AudioFileGetProperty (*file, kAudioFilePropertyFileFormat, &formatSize, &format);
  return (kAudioFileCAFType==format);
}
```